# how to suppress keyboard input

Tags: c#, input

So I am trying to make a program that disables all keyboard input but can still detect when a key is being pressed (doesn't matter which).

I tried using the `BlockInput` method but it blocked ALL input (mouse and keyboard) and wouldn't allow for further detection of keyboard press.

This is my current code (function is a timer with a 1 tick interval)

```
private void detect_key_press_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process p = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        if (p != null)
        {
            IntPtr h = p.MainWindowHandle;
            //SetForegroundWindow(h);
            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
            {
                //SendKeys.SendWait("k");
                this.BackColor = Color.Red;

            }
            else
            {
                this.BackColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I do this please? Thanks.

**EDIT**

I tried

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
```

but no success. Keys still get proccessed.

Comment: A timer will not work. You should hook the keyboard.

Comment: I have looked. How do you create such a hook.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use Windows Forms ?

If you set the KeyPreview on your form to true and create an event on the KeyDown for the form, you can handle the keyboard input that way.

```
private void Form1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.KeyData == Keys.S) // some accepted key
    //Do something with it
  else 
  {
    //or cancel the key entry
    e.Handled = true;
    e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: The keys get disabled while typing in the main control. But I want to disable it keyboard input in general.

Comment: Do you want to disable system wide input ? I doubt you can do that with a Managed application.